# tor error on Ubuntu

Tags: tor

When I type and enter `tor` on terminal this message is shown:

```
Sep 02 01:00:34.889 [notice] Tor 0.3.2.10 (git-0edaa32732ec8930) running on Linux with Libevent 2.1.8-stable, OpenSSL 1.1.1, Zlib 1.2.11, Liblzma 5.2.2, and Libzstd 1.3.3.
Sep 02 01:00:34.889 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Sep 02 01:00:34.889 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
Sep 02 01:00:34.894 [notice] Scheduler type KIST has been enabled.
Sep 02 01:00:34.894 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Sep 02 01:00:34.894 [warn] Could not bind to 127.0.0.1:9050: Address already in use. Is Tor already running?
Sep 02 01:00:34.894 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Failed to bind one of the listener ports.
Sep 02 01:00:34.894 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
```

Comment: I recommend that you **[edit]** this to include a description of how you obtained and installed tor, as well as to clarify whether or not tor *is* already running, as far as you know.

Answer (score 1):

The error message, "`Could not bind to 127.0.0.1:9050: Address already in use. Is Tor already running?`" means that this cony of `tor` couldn't get exclusive use of port `9050` on `localhost`, and even suggests a possible reason.

You could find out if `tor` is still running with

```
pgrep tor
```

and kill it with

```
pkill -9 tor
```

Comment: this isn't work for me

Comment: What exactly does "isn't work for me" mean? Do you get error messages? No results? Does `sudo lsof -i tcp:9050` show anything? Is the port still open?

Answer (score 0):

By default when you install the `tor` package it has created a service and will run Tor in the background. Eg. you can see the service status by running:

```
service tor status
```

It should say `active` and this means it's running.